# Multiple points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I need to find multiple points and tangent lines in the curves given. I need to know if my solutions to (a) and (c) are correct and how to find tangent lines in (b) and (d).

(a) $Y^3-Y^2+X^3-X^2+3XY^2+3X^2Y+2XY=f(X,Y)$
$f_Y=3Y^2-2Y+6XY+3X^2+2X-(1)$

$f_X=3X^2-2X+6XY+3Y^2+2Y -(2)$

(1)-(2);
$2(X-Y)=0$

Multiple points at $(a,a)$.

$F_2=2XY-Y^2-X^2 = -(Y-X)^2$ Tangent line at $(0,0) :Y=X$.

Tangent line at $(a,a)(a\neq 0):12a^2(X-a)+12a^2(Y-a)=0 \implies X+Y=2a.$

(b)
$f(x,y)=X^4+Y^4-X^2Y^2$

$f_X=4X^3-2XY^2=2X[2X^2-Y^2]=2X[\sqrt 2X-Y][\sqrt 2X+Y]$

$f_Y= 4Y^3-2X^2Y=2Y[\sqrt 2Y-X][\sqrt 2Y+X].$

$f_X=f_Y=0 \implies $ multiple point at $(0,0)$.

How do I find the tangent line in this case?
(c)

$X^3+Y^3-3X^2-3Y^2+3XY+1=f(X,Y)\\f_X=3X^2-6X+3Y-(1)\\f_Y=3Y^2-6Y+3X-(2)\\(1)-(2)\implies 3X^2-6X+3Y-3Y^2+6Y-3X\\=3(X-Y)(X-Y)-9(X-Y)$

$=3(X-Y)[X+Y-3]=0\implies X=Y$  or  $X+Y=3$

Multiple points at $(a,a)$ and $(a, 3-a).$

$f_X|_{(a,a)}=3a^2-3a=3a(a-1).\\f_Y|_{(a,a)}=3a^2-3a=3a(a-1).$

Tangent line at $a\neq 0,1;\\3a(a-1)(X-a)+3a(a-1)(Y-a)=0\\X+Y-2a=0.$

$f_X|_{(a,3-a)}=3a^2-3a+3(a-1)=3a^2-6a+9\neq 0$ for $a\in\mathbb R.$

$f_Y|_{(a,3-a)}=3[(3-a)^2]-6(3-a)+3a=3a^2-9a+9\neq 0$ for $a\in\mathbb R.$

Tangent at $(a,3-a):\\(3a^2-6a+9)(X-a)+(3a^2-9a+9)(Y-3+a)=0$.

(d)

$Y_2+(X^2-5)(4X^4-20X^2+25)=f(X,Y)\\Y^2+4X^6-20X^4-20X^4+25X^2+100X^2-125=Y^2+4X^6-40X^4+125X^2-125=f(X,Y)$

$f_Y=2Y, f_X=24X^5-160X^3+250X.\\f_X=0\implies X(12X^4-80X^2+125)=0\\X(6X^2-25)(2X^2-5)=0$

Multiple points at $(0,0),(0,\pm \frac {5}{\sqrt 6}),(0,\pm \sqrt {\frac {5}{2}})$

How do I find the tangent line?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

(picture for exercice (a) added by JeanMarie for a better understanding)

Comment: You could take advantage of the fact that $f(x,y)=(x+y)^3-(x-y)^2.$

Comment: I have added a picture for a better understanding (I included it into your text with a kind of disclaimer, saying it is on my own reponsability instead of beginning an answer because I have 2 or 3 times a bad experience with the latter solution). I advise you, for such problems to plot **always** to a curve, in order to check or to foresee the results. Is it in conformity with your results ?

Comment: 2 things for question a): 1) the equation of the tangent looks good but should be simpified into $y=x$ 2) Don't you think in particular that speaking about point $(a,a), a \neq 0$ is rather strange.

Comment: The lecturer that has given you homework (b) is a funny guy: curve (b) is reduced to the single point $(0,0)$ !!!

Comment: Why haven't you tried to comment on my comments and the curve I have provided for point (a) ?

Comment: Hey. I'm sorry. Thank you very much for your help. What is wrong with the point $$ (a,a), a \neq 0 $$? Is it wrong?

Comment: Also what about (b)? I tried sketching and thought it must have a tangent at $$ (0,0) $$. Is that correct?

Comment: (a) It is visible that the only point having coordinates $(a,a)$ AND belonging to the curve is (0,0). (b) The problem is that that the curve for (c) is reduced to this point (0,0) : there is no other point...

Comment: Got the part (a). I don't understand the other parts. Can you please explain some more?

Comment: Do we agree that all your curves have equation $f(x,y)\color{red}{=0}$ ?
In the case (b) (not (c) my bad ; I have not worked on (c)): $0=f(x,y)=x^4+y^4−x^2y^2=(x^2-y^2)^2+(xy)^2$: we are with a sum of squares, that can never be 0, but for the very special case where these squares are simultaneously zero, i.e., for $x=y=0$: the origin is the only point of the curve !

Comment: Great! Got it. Can you help me with the other two as well?

Comment: Sorry, no time left. I must deliver a lecture now. Have a good day.